# Access JSON data - undefined

Tags: javascript, json

I have this json:

```
{
"total": 1,
"per_page": "10",
"current_page": 1,
"last_page": 1,
"next_page_url": null,
"prev_page_url": null,
"from": 1,
"to": 1,
"data": [
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Artista di prova",
        "artist_hash": "Gqrrx6NrtqqMpvEN",
        "spotify_followers": null,
        "spotify_popularity": 66,
        "image_small": null,
        "image_large": null,
        "fully_scraped": 0,
        "updated_at": "2016-11-06 08:21:02",
        "bio": "",
        "wiki_image_large": null,
        "wiki_image_small": null,
        "tracks": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Traccia di prova",
                "album_name": "Album di prova",
                "number": 1,
                "duration": 18133,
                "artists": [
                    "Artista di prova"
                ],
                "youtube_id": null,
                "spotify_popularity": 50,
                "album_id": 1,
                "temp_id": null,
                "url": "http://myapp.app/track/1/mov/stream",
                "artist_id": 2
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Traccia di prova 2",
                "album_name": "Album di prova",
                "number": 1,
                "duration": 18133,
                "artists": [
                    "Artista di prova"
                ],
                "youtube_id": null,
                "spotify_popularity": 50,
                "album_id": 1,
                "temp_id": null,
                "url": "http://myapp.app/track/1/mov/stream",
                "artist_id": 2
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

I need to access to the `tracks` field and get all the data.
I tried with:

```
$http.get('artist', {params:params}).success(function(response) {
            $scope.items = response.data;
            $scope.tracks = response.data.tracks;

            console.log($scope.tracks);


        })
    };
```

But I get `undefined`.

How can I access to `tracks` field?

Comment: use `response.data[0].tracks`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` property of response is an array, so you need to access it by index:

```
response.data[0].tracks;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that `tracks` is an array of objects and also, remember that it sits under the `data` key which is also an array. The naive way will be to get each data with their respective index, as such:
`response.data[0].tracks[anotherIndex]` to get one object in the array and `response.data[0].tracks` to log the array.
In a real world scenario though, you may want to properly loop over the `data` and `tracks` and render their values on your component.